# Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH when trying to install Rails 3.0.3

Tags: permissions, installation, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to install rails 3.0.3 and i get the following error every time:

```
Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
```

When I check to see if it installed I get this error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:827:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:261:in `activate'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:68:in `gem'
 from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Sorry, I'm a newb!

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You need to secure that directory before the install. Use:

```
chmod o-w /usr/local
```

to do this. If that doesn't work, the you probably need to be `root` (or otherwise suitably empowered) so you can try:

```
sudo chmod o-w /usr/local
```

and enter your password.

I've seen this sort of thing before on some software which really wants things set up in a certain way to ensure that its assumptions are met. In any case, it's actually a bad idea to have world writable directories except when you *know* security on them is not a big deal.

`/usr/local` is important enough that you *shouldn't* allow anyone to write to it.

Comment: when I try your command this is the result i get:

chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local: Operation not permitted

Could you explain what's going on here? Cause I'm not sure I understand what happening.

Comment: You won't be able to do that as a regular user. You'll need to either be `root` or able to run `sudo chmod blah blah blah`.

Comment: you have to do this recursively, sudo chmod o-w -R /usr/local

Comment: Tried a few other solutions first. If you have a fresh mac and are just settings it up, this is most likely your solution as it was for myself.

Answer (score 16):

For osx it's: `sudo chmod -R o-w /usr/local`

Comment: It's fixed it for me but only with the recursive flag `-R`.
sudo was not necessary for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run:

```
sudo chmod o-w -R /usr/local
```